# 10k per second request postgres

Tags: spring, postgresql

I have a spring worker application that getting messages from Rabbitmq with concurrency 50, and this message, spring application checking variables in DB and with the message, and inserting new results of difference, to DB(for one message to get the difference, we are sending about 5-20 'select' requests, 1 - 5 insert, 1-5 update to DB).

Now problem is that the spring worker application, it uploading very slow to DB when setting concurrency to 200. (200k messages inserted about two days).

And beside this, I have another spring application for monitoring. And everything working very slow, Db, worker app, monitoring app.

How I can do it fastly and optimize. Should I use the Postgres cluster? Or I can implement it in another way.

My Postgres server (intel Xeon 10 cores, 60 GB ram, 1,6TB SSD)

Answer (score 1):

You can use shared cache, load your data on application startup, update your cache in case of update/create operation. Get from cache whatever you want, no need to go in DB